# Drop idle connection in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, agroal

I want a database connection that has gone idle to be dropped once its maxLifetime has been reached.

How can we do this in quarkus? Is this achieved with these 2 properties?

quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime

How can I check that idle connections are actually being dropped? Any logs I can activate?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue by any chance?